# Visual Studio 2010 Creating application that compiles code

Tags: c#, c++, c, compilation

I want to be able to compile code from another application that I created.

#### Long story:

I'm working on creating a 2D engine from scratch using SDL (Please no comments about what is better to use). I understand how to use the SDL Libraries and can create simple games. However, I want to endeavor on bigger projects, but I need to create an application to help me organize the code and overall system. Basically, this program is to be an editor (much like how unity or UDK is, but not as advanced of course). Programming the actual application with code editor and such isn't hard, but my question is about how I can take that code and have it compiled, run, and/or export as an exe? (Taking the code and scripts and putting them into an architecture for compiling isn't the issue, it's the knowing how to compile it idea).

This is a new idea for me and googling didn't give me the results I wanted so I decided to come to StackOverflow because I've gotten many questions answered here before without having to ask (you guys are great btw).

#### TL;DR Version:

Compile code from another self made application.

(My idea is to use C# for the interface or gui and then C/C++ for the actual engine)

Comment: So.. Visual Studio *doesn't* fulfill that project-management need? Even with TFS? I'm not a game-programmer, so it is likely I'm missing something obvious, but still...

Comment: @WhozCraig - agreed.  VS supports multiple projects per solution, can compile C#, C++, and C.  What else is missing?

Comment: Do you have some years time? Compilers are not easy to make, and they are much harder to make for general purpose languages. Full-fledged compilers have tens or hundreads of manyears of development time. But as far as I see, you only need a way to *call* a compiler, if what you produce in your editor is a known language for that a compiler exists.

Comment: Are you asking how to make a compiler, or how to use the compilers already there, just replacing the Visual Studio editor? If the latter, look into msbuild.

Comment: @ArneMertz I don't think he's looking to invent a compiler. He wants to know how to integrate the VC tools into a separate development environment (like Eclipse, or Sublime, etc) of his authoring. I think the second part of your comment is along the right line.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to reinvent the wheel. What needs do you have, that Visual Studio can't satisfy?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on what I would do (at least for the development period): 
**Use existing components.** Namely an editor and a scripting compiler;

For your editor you can use [Avalon Edit](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor)

For your compile/script needs use [CS-Script](http://www.csscript.net/)

You can be up and running in 4-5 hours with these, and you can pretty much hot-swap entity scripts with a little work.

Just have a basic exe that can read a root script file for the project and begin running it.

Hell, I'd be willing to bet you could even grab the assembly that CS-Script makes in memory and save it for use later.

IF you then get past the "Making-A-New-Engine-Wheel-Reinvention" phase, you can come back and support other languages.

Comment: thanks for the resources, I'll make sure to look into them this weekend. The main point of this program is to learn how to create a new engine and/or tools. I plan on using this is not only future projects but also to show to employers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about building a visual editing environment like Unity - something that can host rendered visuals, UI handles on game engine variables, audio editing, as well as script editing and compilation of those scripts then you will need to use something like MSBuild.

Since you state that you have the packaging and management of the project files under control, and assuming that you are intending to build this custom interface to make modifications to files referenced by a visual studio solution, then all you need to do is to call MSBuild with the appropriate command line arguments.

see : [MSBuild (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/ms164311.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If your talking more about the editing side, then maybe Visual Studio Shell:  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Extensibility) says the following:

> Visual Studio 2008 introduced the Visual Studio Shell that allows for development of a customized version of the IDE. The Visual Studio Shell defines a set of VSPackages that provide the functionality required in any IDE. On top of that, other packages can be added to customize the installation. The Isolated mode of the shell creates a new AppId where the packages are installed. These are to be started with a different executable. It is aimed for development of custom development environments, either for a specific language or a specific scenario. The Integrated mode installs the packages into the AppId of the Professional/Standard/Team System editions, so that the tools integrate into these editions.[16] The Visual Studio Shell is available as a free download.

You could make this shell call any compiler(s)...a *lot* of work though.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the following:

```
var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "CompilerVersion", "v3.5" } });
var parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll" }, "foo.exe", true);
parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
CompilerResults results = csc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters,
@"using System.Linq;
    class Program {
      public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var q = from i in Enumerable.Rnge(1,100)
                  where i % 2 == 0
                  select i;
      }
    }");

results.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>().ToList().ForEach(error => Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorText));
```

This code will compile the code in the `results` variable and output it to `foo.exe`.

Comment: sweet, I'll have a try with this and see where I get it to go. Anyway to get the exe to run? (without having to click on it of course)